# AutoML / Data science - Prediction websites

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

Are there any websites where we can simply upload a training dataset with labels, and get predictions for a test dataset ?

Google AutoML and MIT ATM would be similar to what I'm looking for, but they seem to be mainly for images & classification problems but I need simple regression prediction as well.

Comment: Why would you not just use R for this, if you already have a dataset built out?

Comment: How automated do you want it?  There is Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/ that has the tools. For Automatic ML, see  https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/01/current-state-automated-machine-learning.html and https://hackernoon.com/a-brief-overview-of-automatic-machine-learning-solutions-automl-2826c7807a2a

Comment: @ERT, i have been trying data-cleaning,CV, stacking etc. through various packages in python, but the number of permutations is too high, and i'm sure others woulda done a better job automating model & parameter selection. Recently I learned there are toolkits like auto-sklearn which do this for you..

Comment: The https://mljar.com is what are you looking for. You upload data with labels, select what kind of algorithm you would like to train and click start.